# X is a connected and compact Hausdorff space with some properties.Prove that X is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^1$.

Tags: general-topology

$X$ is a connected and compact Hausdorff space,and for all $x \in X$,there is a open neighborhood of $x$ homeomorphic to $(-1,1)$.Prove that $X$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^1$.
At first,I replace X with $\mathbb{S}^1$.Naturally,I tried to prove that $X/\{x\}$ is homeomorphic to $(-1,1)$,but I found it hard to prove this.
So anyone could help me with my proof or have some other ideas?

Comment: Try with $t \mapsto e^{i\pi t}$, $t \in (-1, 1)$.

Comment: How about general X?

Comment: I think we need $X$ to be second countable for this to be true. Extended Long line seems to be a counterexample.